# Converting bytes into two-digit, hexadecimal numbers

Tags: c++, int, hex

```
testRead = testRead.toHex();
std::vector<int> testHexSet;
for(int i = 1; i != testRead.length() + 1; i = i + 2) {
    int iValue = ((int)testRead[i-1] * 16) + (int)testRead[i];
    testHexSet.push_back(iValue);
}
```

Above code is my unsuccessful attempt to convert testRead (QByteArray which is basically char[]), which's contents look like this:

```
f0f1f2
```

into three integers. What I've got, when the input is like the above, is:

```
{1680, 1681, 1682}
```

so not even close (btw. HOW does "f" equal 105?). I'm more than sure it's because it's taking the numbers as decimals - how to tell it that these are actually hexadecimals? I could add every pair of chars to single string and use strtol to convert to integers but is it really way to go?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `f0f1f2`, do you mean it consists of those characters as a string? Or do you mean it consists of hex values? If so, which? 0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2? Or 0xf0f1f2? Or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You´re calculation is based on ASCII numbers, ie. 102 for 'f' and 48 for '0'.
Substract '0' (=48) from each char between 0 and 9 before the calculation
and `('a'-10)` for the rest (lower case)

Comment: If testRead contains uppercase letters, then subtract `'A'-10`.

Comment: @deviantfan I've edited my question, still getting strange numbers... I probably misunderstood something.

Comment: @smsware: he means that you're using characters. `'0'` is a character. You cannot treat ASCII characters as integers outright; you'd need to convert them first.

Comment: @AndyG - I've just figured. It's 6:30am, sorry. ;-)